# How to change the default values of start and count parameters when picking the companies followed by a user in linkedin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, linkedin-api

I am making a web-application in ASP.NET. I have used oauth to get profile fields of a user. I need the names of the companies followed by the user, but the problem is that the default value is set to 20. so, if the user is following more than 20 companies i am not able to get it. Please tell me how can i modify the start and count values. Iv used this url to make the call http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(following:(people,companies,industries,news-sources),educations).. Please help asap..

```
var requestHeader = GetUserProfileAuthorizationHeader();
        var queryString = CreateQueryString();
        var request = WebRequest.Create(RequestProfileUrl + queryString);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", requestHeader.ToString());
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
        try
        {
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                return responseText;
            }
        }
```

Here `public static string RequestProfileUrl = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(following:(companies:(id,name,size,industry),industries))";`  And the method CreateQueryString() does this `queryString = "?format=xml";`    whenever i try to add something like `queryString = "?format=xml&start=0&count=40";`  it gives error dispite the number of companies followed being more than 60.. maybe i need to pass the query parameters in between the RequestProfileUrl i.e near the company somehow..

Comment: Please help guys... i am badly stuck...

Comment: Please post the exact URL you are using, the one you posted doesn't seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding ?start=x&count=y to the url?

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you're getting an error when you add query parameters to the URL, you're not adding those parameters in the way that your OAuth library expects them to be added.  You need to figure out how to add the parameters so they're added to the signature generation process or your signature will be invalid and you'll get a 401 error back from the server.

Comment: can you please tell me where to get a help on this.. iv a method to add query parameter and iv added it there.. it still gives an error, whenever i run it adding those parameters.

Comment: It looks to me like the requestHeader creating your signature has no idea about the queryString you're adding.  Since I don't know how your OAuth implementation works, I can only encourage you to use an existing OAuth library (or signing library) - or find out how the GetUserProfileAuthorizationHeader creates the signature so you can add information about the parameters as well.